# Unable to create a folder : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, directory

Here my code is

```
 Dim folderPath As String = "D:\con"
 If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
 End If
```

What i am trying to achieve is :

1. create a directory named `con` in `D:\` but it throwing error `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\'.`
2. Then i tried manually to create the same in file explorer, it again throws error as `The specified device name is invalid`

Why it is not allowed to create a directory named `Con`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NUL, AUX, CON, COM1-4, LPT1-3, and PRN
```

are reserved words used for DOS Devices

These are specified in IO.SYS and date back from the early MS Dos days. Here is a brief list:

```
CLOCK$ - System clock
CON - Console; combination of keyboard and screen to handle input and output
AUX or COM1 - First serial communicationport
COMn - Second, Third, ... communicationport
LPT1 or PRN - First parallel port
NUL - Dummy port, or the "null device" which we all know under Linux as /dev/null.
CONFIG$ - Unknown
```